# cant find webapplication scoped feature anywhere

Tags: 2007, feature, site-collection, stsadm, web-application

I developed a Custom Timer Job Feature using WSP Builder but for some reason I am not able to find it so that I can activate it.

I know I can activate it using stsadm but why cant I find it in Site Features or Site Collection Features even tho I tried to look into Central admin but couldn't find anything meaningful to solve this issue.

here's Feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature  Id="GUID"
          Title="anotherTimerJob"
          Description="Description for anotherTimerJob"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Hidden="FALSE"
          Scope="WebApplication"
          DefaultResourceFile="core"
          ReceiverAssembly="anotherTimerJob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*************"
          ReceiverClass="anotherTimerJob.anotherTimerJobReceiver"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

**Edited**

If I try this STSADM it says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

stsadm -o activatefeature -id GUIDID -url https://abc303.development.com/portal

**Edited 2**

I was calling Wrong Constructor in class(extended to SPJobDefinition)

I was calling this Method in my receiver class

```
   public anotherTimerJob()
        : base()
    { 
    }
```

when I was suppose to call this one

```
public anotherTimerJob(SPWebApplication webApp)
    : base(TIMERJOB_NAME, webApp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
{ 
    this.Title = TIMERJOB_NAME; 
}
```

Comment: I did deployed it successfully using WSP Builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope for feature is at **"Web Application"** level feature and therefore be visible at

> Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Application
>   Features

[See technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262856%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

**Edited**

You can activate Web Application Feature by giving it's url.

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -id GUIDID -url https://abc303.development.com/
```

If you're facing some problem during Feature Activation then you can debug it by [attaching debugger to the "w3p.exe" process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jannemattila/archive/2008/10/30/attaching-debugger-to-w3wp-exe-using-nice-and-easy-keyboard-shortcut.aspx) in the Visual Studio. In such case, you manually have to activate feature from GUI (Central Admin), not via stsadm.

Hope it helps